# submit form from jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, forms

I have a form on a page, and prior to submitting the user is presented with a jquery dialog. The div for the jquery dialog is within the form. In the dialog is a `<input type="image"/>` which is used to submit the form.

Now this (input image submit) was working before it was placed inside a jquery modal dialog. For some reason the modal is blocking the form submission. Im sure this is probably a "feature". but cannot see how I can overide it.

I need that input to be used to submit the form, and not JS as the struts framework in the back end decides what to do based on which input image has been clicked.

Can anyone help with this problem?

Here is a very basic jsFiddle of the problem http://jsfiddle.net/xi4xi4/CMPYD/5/

Comment: Can you please share your code ?

Comment: what is this element ?
`<input src="" type="image" title="no image to link to but this is the alt" />` and where is the submit button ?

Comment: @Diode It's an input button. It will do the submit - see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_src

Comment: Ah, I have discovered why. Jquery has placed the dialog outside of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't you just add this to your dialog definition?:

```
close: function(event, ui) {
    var test2Value = $('#pop input[name=test2]').val()
    // Do some validation if necessary on test2
    //Set a hidden input so the server side knows what image button was pressed
    $("#some_hidden_field").val('image1');
    $("#george").submit();
}
```

Comment: but its all part of the same form. Also as I said in the question, the struts framework calculates what to do based on which form submit button is hit. so a simple .submit() will now work.

Comment: ok, I see what you mean. I just altered the comment, but the idea is the same. Just submit the form on close of the dialog.

Comment: This would not work. The server side code detects which <input type="image" is pressed to know which processing to do

Comment: @MarkW You're going to have to put some hidden input in your form and have each of your submit images set this value in order for your server side code to detect what was pressed.